# Chamando função com onclick

Tags: javascript, html, html5, dom

Galera eu não consigo chamar uma função usando o onclick, chamando ela direto da tag html vem normal mas se eu chamar de forma não obstrutiva sem chance já li varios docs tentei n maneiras e nada alguem pode dar uma luz.

```
document.getElementById("btSoyouzm").onclick=function(){buscaImagem()};

function buscaImagem(){
        alert("teste do onclick")
}
```

Comment: Tentou `window.onload`?

Comment: Não seria isso: <input type="button" value="MyButton" onclick="buscaImagem" />  ?

Comment: Funciona bem para mim... http://jsfiddle.net/yhfvY/ Pode re-criar o problema no jsFiddle?

Comment: @MatheusBessa isso funciona, porém não queria marcar no html.

Comment: @Sergio funciona =/, agora porque que na pagina não funciona ja tirei e coloquei onload mil vezes.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento já tentei com e sem window.onload

Comment: @HeltonSS, coloque o código no fundo da página. Antes do `</body>`. Se não funcionar precisa colocar mais código aqui ou seguir uma das respostas abaixo.

Comment: @Sergio coloquei o código no final da página como disse e todas respostas funcionaram... não entendi bem o que aconteceu mas vou buscar estudar esse erro, se alguém tiver uma boa explicação, geralmente so colocava no final da página quando estava para subir o arquivo.

Comment: @HeltonSS, se funcionou no final da página então é porque falta `window.onload = function(){ /* o seu codigo aqui */};` Pode testar com isso?

Comment: @Sergio por incrivel que pareça o codigo todo o momento estava com o window.onload vou pesquisar se alguém já teve tal erro. grato pela atenção de todos.

Comment: Dê um exemplo do problema usando o [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 4):

Tenta assim caro amigo

```
document.getElementById("btSoyouzm").addEventListener("click", buscaImagem, false); 

function buscaImagem(){
        alert("teste do onclick")
}
```

Documentação : [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener)

Comment: Porque o downvoter? o que tem de errado com a resposta?

Comment: Tá certo a resposta do @Silvio Andorinha!

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha tenho o seguinte retorno do browser "add event not is defined";

Comment: @HeltonSS qual browser você está usando?

Comment: @HeltonSS sugiro uma implementação cross-browser como na minha resposta :D

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha cara para os teste eu sempre uso o firefox e o chrome.

Comment: Era para ter funcionado porque o `addEventListener` funciona no chrome e no filefox

Answer (score 2):

Para implementar um evento OnClick dinamicamente você precisa adicionar esse evento ao objeto DOM com o `addEventListener` como na resposta do @SilvioAndorinha, entretanto essa implementação é diferente em outros navegadores nesse caso você pode utilizar uma função para fazer está implementação cross-browser.

Sua Função

```
function buscaImagem(){
        alert("teste do onclick")
}
```

Javascript addEvent cross-browser

```
var addEvent = function(elem, type, eventHandle) {
    if (elem == null || typeof(elem) == 'undefined') return;
    if ( elem.addEventListener ) {
        elem.addEventListener( type, eventHandle, false );
    } else if ( elem.attachEvent ) {
        elem.attachEvent( "on" + type, eventHandle );
    } else {
        elem["on"+type]=eventHandle;
    }
};

addEvent(document.getElementById("btSoyouzm"), "click", function(){
  buscaImagem();
});
```

ou

```
addEvent(document.getElementById("btSoyouzm"), "click",buscaImagem);
```

Comment: cara eu ja havia tentado sua resposta e também não deu resultado a unica diferença é que não deu erro no console.

Comment: Aqui esta o teste http://jsfiddle.net/vTv8T/

Comment: Galera vou testar em outra maquina não tem cabimento o que esta acontecendo, prometo dar o feedback depois.